# Is there any alternative to Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java

I need to perform some waiting between one call and another.
Problem is that this waiting will be made in a library so it is not a good practice to put a Thread.sleep() there. No swing involved, this library is a jna interface.

So..is there any alternative suited for my case?

Comment: Blocking call? How about `wait()` method?

Comment: You could also just spawn off another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). For example:

```java
var scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);


var scheduledFuture = scheduler.schedule(this::method,  5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


public String method() {
    System.out.println("Executed!");
    return "Called!";
}
```

First a `ScheduledExecutorService` is created with one thread in.

Then an anonymous implementation of the `Callable` interface is created and passed to the `schedule()` method. The two last parameters specify that the `Callable` should be executed after 5 seconds.

Comment: We are in Java 8, needs more lambda :)